# Java - Split string with multiple dash

Tags: java, split

I want to get an output **first-second** from the string below:

```
first-second-third
```

So basically what i want is to get the string before the last dash (-).
Can anyone give me a best solution for this?

Comment: Get the lastIndefOf("-") and than get the substring from 0 to this index for you it's not ok?

Comment: read the doc of `String.split`

Comment: use substring for get the last dash eg. lastindexof

Comment: [`lastIndexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) -- and if you were wondering about all the downvotes, that's because the solution to this problem can be found so easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, many down votes but I'll add a solution

the most efficient way to do that is using java.lang.String#**lastIndexOf**, which returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified character, searching backwards

lastIndexOf will return -1 if dash does not exist

```
String str = "first-second-third";
int lastIndexOf = str.lastIndexOf('-');
System.out.println(lastIndexOf);
System.out.println(str.substring(0, lastIndexOf)); // 0  represent to cut from the beginning of the string
```

output:

> 12
>
> first-second

Comment: "_Well, many down votes because it is an easy question_". Actually, the reason for downvote is : "_This question does not show any research effort_". (hover the button, you will see ;) )

Comment: @IddoE how about if there is no dash? It throws an exception

Comment: @Makudex Are you asking now how to write an if-statement...? I think this is the page where you should start your adventure with Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Comment: @Makudex lastIndexOf will return -1 if the character (dash in this case) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "first-second-third";
String newString = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

Comment: Point taken and answered fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just an another way other than **lastIndex** method,  using regex too can be done, try below code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(.*)-.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("first-second-third");
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Comment: This doesn't work the same as `lastIndexOf`. For example, it wouldn't work if you've got a newline in the input.